# MS SQL, Cant use just the Table name anymore

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im doing the following in a SQL Query from SQL Server Management:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
```

Which looks like it works for some other tables when executed in a Procedure. But for this specific table I have to do:

```
SELECT * FROM databasename.dbo.tablename
```

In both a single query and in a procedure or i get the following Error: Message 208 Invalid object name.

I've tried doing this as well:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.tablename
```

Table schema is set to dbo and my users default schema is also dbo. Also this is a newly installed server and the database is a restored database from another server.

Im new to SQL so its probably something stupid but I cant find the answer anywhere.

**EDIT**

I fixed it. I was stupid and didn't know about reserved keywords. The table name was User and hence I needed to use Brackets []. [tablename]

Comment: does the table `tablename` exist in that DB? check whether the name is same or different?

Comment: You probably landed in the master Database. look for a drop down in the top left corner of SSMS.  Rafal's answer will help as well.

Comment: It's a good idea to keep a list of SQL's reserved words, and make sure that you don't use them for table names.  Everywhere I go seems to have an "order" table, and this same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution that may help you is:

```
Use databasename;
GO

select * from tablename
```

Comment: Yes.  The `USE` directive tells the server which db to use as default for that connection.  Note that if you try to access a table in a database other than the one specified, you will need to use the full `database.dbo.tablename`

Comment: I tried the Use command I did this:      USE Databasename;      Go      Select * From tablename  But now i get Inncoret syntax near keyword tablename

Comment: I fixed it. I was stupid and didn't know about reserved words. The table name was User and hence I needed to use Brackets [].